# OleDbCommand ExecuteNonQuery() performance issues

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I'm currently trying to write a huge amount of datasets to an access database.
Unfortunately `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` seems to be very slow and I'm looking for a faster approach.

I've been measuring the execution time of all parameter adds,
but one execution including all of them is not even one millisecond. So that's not a factor.
I've also been trying to put all pages from all languages and all modules into one List which didn't made any difference as well.
One execution time of `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`on the other hand is at average 200 milliseconds.

Here is my Code:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Program.connectionString))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand($"INSERT INTO {Program.NameOfDatabaseTable}([name],[language],[module],[path],[numberoflinks]) VALUES(@1, @2, @3, @4, @5)", connection))
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    foreach (Language currlang in Program.Languages) {
                        ShowPercentProgress("Writing to Database... ", counter, Program.Languages.Count());
                        counter++;
                        foreach (Module currmodule in currlang.Modules) {
                            foreach(Page currpage in currmodule.pages) {

                                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@1", currpage.name));
                                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@2", currpage.language));
                                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@3", currpage.module));
                                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@4", currpage.path));
                                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@5", OleDbType.Integer) { Value = currpage.linklist.Count() });

                                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Writing Data to Database succesfull.");
                }
            }
```

I'd like to know if there is any way to put multiple datasets within one `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` in order to reduce the runtime.
As a side question: Is it possible somehow not to insert the Database table name directly into the SQL string (To avoid SQL Injection)?

Comment: You should use batch inserts. Executing every insert statement in a for loop is always going to be slow.

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` for the relevant table so we can see the column names and datatypes.

Comment: In OleDB there is no batch insert unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of researching I got to accept that OleDb has simply no possibility to batch insert / improve the performance. Therefore I switched to System.Data.SQLConnection in order to use the Batch Insert and speed up performance. Instead of Access I've created a SQLite DB.

So don't waste your time trying to work with Access. For small Datasets Access might be an option. But when you have a bigger Dataset, I'd recommend working with SQLite.